# Vector SIMD types in Swift

Tags: vector, types, swift, simd

I was wondering if it's possible to use the SIMD types defined in `<simd/simd.h>` (such as `vector_float3`) in Swift. I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: While it's not exactly a replacement for a real SIMD library, GLKit has math routines that can be used as general-purpose for common vectors and matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a heads up for this question for it to be up to date - SIMD Vectors have been announced at **WWDC '15** for *Swift 2.0*:

> SIMD Support:Clang extended vectors are imported and usable in Swift, enabling many graphics and other
>   low-level numeric APIs (e.g. simd.h) to be usable in Swift.

So the answer from now on - yes, it's possible.

Comment: Any idea how you import it - I can't find anything online other than that extract that you have copied above. It isn't imported automatically as far as I can tell. Thanks.

Comment: Just import simd.h. There's not a lot of external documentation available, but the header has enough information to see what's available.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like not for now. They might be adding it in a later version, though. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swift-language/slwe62yKsWo

Comment: Please report a bug to request this feature if it would be useful to you!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 comes with a native support for [SIMD vector types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/simd_vector_types). The following Playground sample code shows an element-wise multiplication using [`SIMD4`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd4):

```
let vector1 = SIMD4(1, 2, 3, 4)
let vector2: SIMD4 = [2, 3, 4, 5]

let vector3 = vector1 &* vector2
print(vector3) // prints: SIMD4<Int>(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

---

Sources: [Swift Evolution - SIMD Vectors proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0229-simd.md)

Answer (score 0):

Here check my repo: https://github.com/noxytrux/SwiftGeom i build whole library for that. So you can now use vec2, vec3 etc in your swift project.